How to make /.singularity.d/libs/libfakeroot.so visible to fakeroot also visible to normal user?
I am building a Singularity container using Apptainer. I installed package libfakeroot using command apt install -y libfakeroot in the definition file in hope that /.singularity.d/libs/libfakeroot.so could be seen by normal user. But because the user is (fake) root when the package libfakeroot is installed, this file is only visible when I shell into the container as a fake root user (shell --fakeroot). If I shell into the container as a normal user (without --fakeroot), the directory /.singularity.d/libs/ is empty. Is there any way to make /.singularity.d/libs/libfakeroot.so visible to fakeroot also visible to a normal user? Thank you.
Environment:

Host OS: RedHat 8.8
Guest OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Apptainer version: 1.2.5

